# Массив данных одного класса в другом классе

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть классы

```
class Voucher {
string date;
int visitors;

};

class Balance {};
```

Как сделать что бы в классе `Balance` выводился список (массив) данных класса `Voucher` например

```
1) "24.12.2018", 6 visitors
2) "13.11.2019", 10 visitors и т.д
```

Comment: Создать массив и вывести каждый его элемент. Вектором например. А инт в это 24.12.2018 как преобразовать даже не догадываюсь.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков это как пример просто

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков я создала в классе Balance Voucher vector [10]; а как можо вывести?

Comment: можно  Balance    делать другом  Voucher,  а можно в Voucher   определить   get_date() const  и  get_visitors() const,  тогда данные в Voucher могут оставаться закрытыми, а Balance может свободно пользоваться его данными, и можно еще через закрытое наследование, если данные в Voucher обьявить как защищенные

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ой благодарю!! очень полезно!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо где то так

```
class Voucher {
public: // иначе будет сложно
int date;
int visitors;

};

class Balance {
private:
  std::vector<Voucher> m_voucher;
public:
void show() {
  for (int i = 0; i < m_voucher.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << (i+1) << ") " << int2strdate(m_voucher[i].date) << ", " << m_voucher[i].visitors << " visitors" << std::endl;
  }
};

std::string int2strdate(int date) {
   // тут как то самостоятельно напишите, я не знаю, как дату сохраняете
   return ...;
}
```

Comment: пишет что вектор не имеет типа при компиляции ошибка( 8 'vector' does not name a type

Comment: Ну так нужно `#include <vector>`

Comment: дату сохраняю как string "24.09.2018" это мне нужно написать return date просто?

Comment: Да. Я почему то решил, что там int , а не string

Comment: Еще ошибка 'int2strdate' was not declared in this scope в цикле

Comment: Удалите эту функцию и ее вызов. Или перенесите выше определения класса

Comment: Спасибо Вадим!! Все получилось!!

Comment: кстати почему то при создании обьекта Balance данные так и не выводяться(( хотя ошибок в коде нет

Comment: Вызывайте функцию show у объекта balance

Comment: все равно не выводит( какая то проблема в цикле может?

Comment: может массив не заполнен данными?

Comment: заполнен, оно даже ") " не выводит

Comment: А у вас работает? или вы е проверяли?

Comment: в приведенном коде явно не хватает кучи кода - ввода/заполнения массива, функции main и  другого. Мне лень писать эти детали. Но я более чем уверен, что оно заработает. Если у Вас никак-никак не хочет работать - создавайте новый вопрос, публикуйте полный код и будем смотреть.

Comment: Сейчас залью свой код . спасибо!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775757/Ошибок-нет-но-не-выводит-данные