# Ошибок нет, но не выводит данные

Tags: c++, ооп

интересует функция `void show ()`    в классе `WeekBalance`, которая должна выводить массив вектор данных класса `Voucher`.

```
#include <iomanip>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;



    class Date {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;

        public:
            Date (int year, int month, int day) {
                this->year = year;
                this->month = month;
                this->day = day;
            }
    };

    class Bus {
        int seatsNumber;
        int petrolPer100km;

        public:
            Bus (int seatsNumber, int petrolPer100km) {
                this->seatsNumber = seatsNumber;
                this->petrolPer100km = petrolPer100km;
            }
    };

    class Person {

        string name;
        string surname;
        Date* birthday;

        public:
            Person ( string name, string surname, Date* birthday) {
                this->name = name;
                this->surname = surname;
                this->birthday = birthday;
            }
    };

    class Application {

        string finalPoint;
        int length; 

        public:
            Application (string finalPoint, int length) {
                this->finalPoint = finalPoint;
                this->length = length;
            }
            friend class WeekBalance;
    };

    class Driver : public Person {
        string category;
        float salary;
        string dateofadmission;

        public:
         Driver (string name, string surname, Date* birthday, string category, float salary, string dateofadmission) : Person ( name, surname, birthday)
        {
            this->category = category;
            this->salary = salary;
            this->dateofadmission = dateofadmission;
        }
    };

    class Voucher : public Bus, public Application, public Driver {
    public:
        int dateofcompletion;
        int petrol;

        public:

            Voucher(int seatsNumber, int petrolPer100km, string finalPoint, int length, string name, string surname, Date* birthday, string category, float salary, string dateofadmission, int dateofcompletion, int petrol ) : Bus (seatsNumber, petrolPer100km), Application (finalPoint, length), Driver(name, surname, birthday, category, salary, dateofadmission) 
            {
                this->dateofcompletion = dateofcompletion;
                this->petrol = petrol;  


            }

    };

    class WeekBalance   {
    private:
      std::vector<Voucher> m_voucher;
    public:

    void show() {

      for (int i = 0; i < m_voucher.size(); i++) {
        cout << (i+1) << ") " << m_voucher[i].dateofcompletion << m_voucher[i].petrol << m_voucher[i].finalPoint <<  endl; // ЦИКЛ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ не выводит данные finalPoint dateofcompletion Petrol
      }
    }
    };

    int main() {
            Date d2 (21,5,2020);

            Voucher (1,2,"lviv", 2, "sda", "sdsd", &d2, "c", 455, "sd", 3, 4);
            Voucher (4,5,"hk", 2, "dd", "sd", &d2, "sd", 3, "sd", 9, 1);

            WeekBalance b; // НЕ ВЫВОДИТ
            b.show();


        return 0;
    }
```

ПРАВИЛЬНО ЛИ Я ЗАПОЛНЯЮ МАССИВЫ

```
void show() {
for (int i = 0; i < m_voucher.size(); i++) {    m_voucher[i].petrol = petrol;}
  for (int i = 0; i < m_voucher.size(); i++) {
    cout << (i+1) << ") " << m_voucher[i].dateofcompletion << m_voucher[i].petrol << m_voucher[i].finalPoint <<  endl;

  }
}
```

Comment: Один я не вижу в приведенном коде заполнения b.m_voucher?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов подскажите как?

Comment: как страшно жить в мире, в котором талончик одновременно **является** и водителем, и автобусом и маршрутом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Это путевка которая наследует информацию об Автобусе Водителе и итд

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов это нужно заполнять прямо в теле цикла?

Comment: Дело в том, что при наследовании отношения между классами  всегда выражаются глаголом "является". Т.е. путевка не "наследует информацию об Автобусе Водителе и итд" а "является Автобусе Водителе и итд". Если такого рода фраза звучит коряво, значит и иерархия классов неправильная.

Comment: @NickEsp, не вдаваясь в глубины терминологии, в ООП (и в С++ особенно) наследование класса Foo классом Bar является заданием отношения «Bar является подтипом Foo». Таким образом человек читающий этот код будет в полной уверенности, что «Путёвка» — это некий биомеханический гибрид Автобуса, Водителя и чего-то-там-ещё. Не настаиваю, что это не так... может я просто давно ни куда не ездил...

Comment: @Fat-Zer :DD ахаха)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0) Научись пользоваться **дебаггером**.

Проблема проста массив пуст.

1)

```
        Voucher (1,2,"lviv", 2, "sda", "sdsd", &d2, "c", 455, "sd", 3, 4);
        Voucher (4,5,"hk", 2, "dd", "sd", &d2, "sd", 3, "sd", 9, 1);
```

на

```
        Voucher v1(1,2,"lviv", 2, "sda", "sdsd", &d2, "c", 455, "sd", 3, 4);
        Voucher v2(4,5,"hk", 2, "dd", "sd", &d2, "sd", 3, "sd", 9, 1);
```

2)

```
class WeekBalance   {
private:
  std::vector<Voucher> m_voucher;
public:

void show() {

  for (int i = 0; i < m_voucher.size(); i++) {
    cout << (i+1) << ") " << m_voucher[i].dateofcompletion << m_voucher[i].petrol << m_voucher[i].finalPoint <<  endl; // ЦИКЛ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ не выводит данные finalPoint dateofcompletion Petrol
  }
}
};
```

на

```
class WeekBalance   {
private:
  std::vector<Voucher> m_voucher;
public:

void add(Voucher v)
{m_voucher.push_back(v);}

void show() {

  for (int i = 0; i < m_voucher.size(); i++) {
    cout << (i+1) << ") " << m_voucher[i].dateofcompletion << m_voucher[i].petrol << m_voucher[i].finalPoint <<  endl; // ЦИКЛ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ не выводит данные finalPoint dateofcompletion Petrol
  }
}
};
```

3)

```
        WeekBalance b; // НЕ ВЫВОДИТ
```

на

```
        WeekBalance b; // НЕ ВЫВОДИТ
        b.add(v1); 
        b.add(v2);
```

Возможно где-то синтаксис не тот но в общем примерно так.

Comment: Никита, Вы меня просто спасли! СПАСИБО!